# Why bean is not found in Spring Boot test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a Spring Boot Application, its file hierarchy:

```
src/
└── main/
    └── java/
    |      ├── com.example/
    |      |         ├── config/ 
    |      |         |     └──R2DBCConfiguration.java
    |      |         ├── dao/
    |      |         |     └── UnitR2DBCRepository.java
    |      |         └── R2DBCApplication.java
    |      └──resources/
    |             └── application.yml
    └── test
        └── java/
               ├── com.example/
               |         └── dao/
               |               └── R2DBCTest.java
               └──resources/
                      └── application.yml
```

R2DBCConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class R2DBCConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder(). ... .build());
    }

    @Bean
    public DatabaseClient databaseClient() {
        return DatabaseClient.builder().connectionFactory(connectionFactory()).build();
    }
}
```

Unit2RDBCRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UnitR2DBCRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Unit, UUID> { }
```

R2DBCApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class R2DBCApplication{
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(R2DBCApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = R2DBCConfiguration.class)
public class R2DBCTest {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseClient client;
    @Autowired
    private UnitR2DBCRepository unitR2DBCRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run R2DBCTest,  I get the error:

NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.dao.UnitR2DBCRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Remove `@ContextConfiguration` from your test. Also why this config class? Spring Boot provides auto-config for these beans.

Comment: If I remove `@ContextConfiguration` , I get another error: InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Reactive Repositories are not supported by JPA. Offending repository is ru.sberbank.ditsib.elt.dao.UnitR2DBCRepository!

Comment: Apparently you are mixing Reactive and JPA in a single application. This requires configuration for which package includes what. If you don't intend to use JPA then remove those dependencies from your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still need JPA. Could you describe how to configure JPA and Reactive in a single application, please?

Comment: You need to add the needed `@ENable` annotations on the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, to specify which packages are for JPA and which are Reactive.